# Setting the status_code in a Oracle Rest Api source type ords.source_type_collection feed service

Tags: sql, oracle, rest, oracle-ords

I have a collection service that fetches all the items linked to an entity and gives a summary for each item with the page functionality given by collection services this works great.

However I have a routine to check if the client running the query has access to the entity searched for on the service. I want to set the status_code to 401 unauthorised if a user searches for an entity they don't have access to, because currently I'm just getting status 200 ok with no records in the query.

Is this even possible with a collection query, if not how do I get the same paged layout without a collection query?

I tried using procedure with an out parameter to bind onto `:status_code`. However since this isn't a plsql block it's failing.

also tried
and `:status_code = 401`
However it's not picking up the implicit parameter `:status_code`.

Comment: first thought is this sounds exactly what you can achieve with our prehook feature - but this would be applied to ALL of your rest services, not just this one API/service.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Thanks, will try the prehook. Just pass in a key in the URI to ensure this only applies to this specific service.